# Difference between @TestSubject and @InjectMocks?

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito

While learning **Mockito** I found two different annotations **@TestSubject** and **@InjectMocks** at below references.
[@TestSubject Ref](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_exception_handling.htm)
[@InjectMocks Ref](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_verifying_behavior.htm)
`@InjectMocks` annotation is working absolutely fine as explained in tutorial but `@TestSubject` doesn't work rather its displaying error.
I'm getting `TestSubject cannot be resolved to a type` error for `@TestSubject` annotation in the below code snippet however I have done proper setup (including **Junit** & **Mockito** jar files in the build path).

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import com.infosys.junitinteg.action.MathApplication;
import com.infosys.junitinteg.service.CalculatorService;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MathApplicationTester {

    // @TestSubject annotation is used to identify class which is going to use
    // the mock object
    @TestSubject
    MathApplication mathApplication = new MathApplication();

    // @Mock annotation is used to create the mock object to be injected
    @Mock
    CalculatorService calcService;

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testAdd() {
        // add the behavior to throw exception
        Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("Add operation not implemented")).when(calcService).add(10.0, 20.0);

        // test the add functionality
        Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.add(10.0, 20.0), 30.0, 0);
    }
}
```

I have two questions here.
 **1. Has some one encountered similar issue? If yes then what was the root cause and solution?

 2. If it's working fine then what is the difference between `@TestSubject` and `@InjectMocks` annotations?**

Comment: I can't really find any proof that this annotation actually exists as part of Mockito. The tutorial you link to doesn't even define an import statement for it. Seems like a typo to me and it should have been `@Spy` for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[@TestSubject](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/TestSubject.html) is the annotation of EasyMock that does the same like Mockito's [@InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/Mockito.html#23). If you're using Mockito then you have to use `@InjectMocks`.